# how to get client_id and client_secret code in cloud foundry using api's

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

In cloud foundry how can I get the client_id and client_secret code.

This will be used in Basic authentication instead of passing the user and password for respective api calls

Comment: This question needs some more context. What do you mean "get the `client_id` and `client_secret`"? Do you mean, you want to get an OAuth token from with a client ID and secret and use that to make API calls?

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is something that you would get from your platform administrator.  He or she would be able to provide you with a properly configured client id and client secret to fit your needs.  If you are not the administrator, then you won't be able to do this.

If you are an administrator, read on.  There are many existing client and secret pairs within a Cloud Foundry platform.  It's also possible, and suggested, to create custom client and secret pairs for use with non-platform apps.  You shouldn't use a platform client for your custom app, you should use your own custom client, that way if the client is compromised you can delete it or change the secret.

All of this, viewing & managing client data, is done through UAA, so I'd recommend starting with the docs on UAA.  Make sure that you understand the concepts.  You may even want to take a step further back and review concepts of OAuth2 as well.  Understanding OAuth2 will make working with UAA much easier.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/uaa/uaa-overview.html

After that, you'll need the `uaac` (i.e. UAA client) installed.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-uaac

Once you're familiar with UAA & have the client installed, this doc on how to manage clients should provide you with instructions to view or create a new client.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/master/docs/Sysadmin-Guide.rst#manage-client-registrations

Answer (score 0):

You will need admin role to be able to create a client or get its details.
Refer https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/api/uaa/version/4.7.1/index.html#clients to see various api to manage and create clients.
You can also use the uaa client to get the client details.
Refer https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/uaa/uaa-user-management.html for more info.